# use client-side js variable in pug

Tags: javascript, pug

Can I somehow use client-side javascript variables in pug file, for loop in objects or in arrays? Like I have some array in client-side js file: var someArray, and I wont too send this array in pug file for loop into it... is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running pug client side (as per the [browser support](https://github.com/pugjs/pug#browser-support) section of the homepage), then you just pass the value into the compiled template.

```
var locals = {
    someName: someArray
}
var fn = pug.compile('string of pug', options);
var html = fn(locals);
```

If you are running pug server side, then you will have to make multiple requests to the server as described in [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).